# Convert Javascript time to MySQL format using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, timestamp

How can I convert a js Date (like this `Sun Jul 13 2014 07:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)`) to MySQL format (like this `2014-07-13 07:00:00`) using php ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your date string already contains the time zone, you don't need to do anything special:

```
$when = new DateTime('Sun Jul 13 2014 07:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)');
echo $when->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

As helpfully noted in comments, this string actually contains two bits of time zone information, *UTC + 2* and *EET* (Eastern European Time), and PHP is basically ignoring the second one. It's spotted better in this example:

```
var_dump(new DateTime('Sun Jul 13 2014 07:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)'), DateTime::getLastErrors());
var_dump(new DateTime('Sun Jul 13 2014 07:00:00 GMT+0200'), DateTime::getLastErrors());
var_dump(new DateTime('Sun Jul 13 2014 07:00:00 (EET)'), DateTime::getLastErrors());
```

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2014-07-13 07:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+02:00"
}
array(4) {
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(1)
  ["warnings"]=>
  array(1) {
    [34]=>
    string(29) "Double timezone specification"
  }
  ["error_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["errors"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2014-07-13 07:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+02:00"
}
array(4) {
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["warnings"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["error_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["errors"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2014-07-13 07:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(2)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "EET"
}
array(4) {
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["warnings"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["error_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["errors"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

We in fact need to strip one of them, e.g.:

```
$js_date_string = 'Sun Jul 13 2014 07:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)';
// Regular expression is shown for illustration purposes, it's probably wrong!
$tmp_date_string = preg_replace('/ GMT\+\d{4}/ui', '', $js_date_string);

$when = new DateTime($tmp_date_string);
var_dump($when, DateTime::getLastErrors());
echo $when->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2014-07-13 07:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(2)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "EET"
}
array(4) {
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["warnings"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["error_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["errors"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
2014-07-13 07:00:00
```

Comment: This does not work for Berlin I guess. Thats my js date: `Mon May 04 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)`. When trying to create a new `DateTime` I receive the error `Double timezone specification`.

Comment: @Adam It's probably what the error message says: you have two time zones. That they're identical half of the year doesn't change that. What if you add several months? do you want to result to be UTC+2 or CEST?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález at the moment they are the same, and I guess the other half of the year js will print `GMT+0100 (Central European Summer Time)`. In your example the string has also two timezones `GMT+0200` and `EET`, but that works for some reason.

Comment: @Adam Ah, sorry, I hadn't noticed that. Interesting... In the question's example PHP is in fact ignoring the `EET` part. Perhaps we just hit a loophole in the parser's code.

Comment: haha, yes maybe. But one can fix it by removing the second timestamp with regex like this: `$cleanDate = preg_replace('/\(.*\)/', '', $jsDate);`.

Comment: @Adam I vote for loophole. Once example triggers a warning, a similar one triggers an error.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to enhance @akuzminsky answer a little. Since `date_parse` is using `strtotime` internally to parse the date, you can use it directly and make your code more flexible.

There is a small drawback since you need to set the time zone in order to use `date` correctly and avoid php warning. I am setting it to `Europe/Athens` but you can find [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) all available codes.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Athens");

$unixTimeStamp = strtotime("Sun Jul 13 2014 07:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)");
$newFormat = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $unixTimeStamp );

echo $newFormat;
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript: 
    This get this time right now in seconds. Dividing by 1000 gets rid of the milliseconds

```
var time = new Date().getTime() / 1000
```

PHP: Use the time returned from JS, the integer value

```
$time = gmdate('H:i:s', time)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
print_r(date_parse("Sun Jul 13 2014 07:00:00 GMT+0200"));
?>


Array
(
[year] => 2014
[month] => 7
[day] => 13
[hour] => 7
[minute] => 0
[second] => 0
[fraction] => 0
[warning_count] => 0
[warnings] => Array
    (
    )

[error_count] => 0
[errors] => Array
    (
    )

[is_localtime] => 1
[zone_type] => 1
[zone] => -120
[is_dst] =>
[relative] => Array
    (
        [year] => 0
        [month] => 0
        [day] => 0
        [hour] => 0
        [minute] => 0
        [second] => 0
        [weekday] => 0
    )

)
```